# Django on shared host and AppEngine speed difference

Tags: django, google-app-engine, cgi

I know it is possible to run Django on shared hosting through CGI or fastCGI however both of 
them are very slow. Now I know that AppEngine also handles Django requests through CGI. I want to know what is the difference that Django on shared hosting cannot be as fast as it is on AppEngine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine does not handle requests using CGI.

The Python 2.5 runtime uses a CGI-like interface that's actually more like FastCGI - if you define a main method, the runtime will call that instead of reimporting the script, and even if you don't, modules are cached between requests.

The Python 2.7 runtime uses WSGI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am quoting this from Website of App Engine:
"Python App Engine applications communicate with the web server using the CGI standard."
from :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld

So the time consuming part is the conversion of WSGI to CGI, right?

Comment: @Naji That's for the 2.5 runtime, which as I just said uses a CGI-like interface - but it's not plain CGI. If it were, the entire app would be loaded, parsed and executed for every request; App Engine avoids that, even in 2.5.